# Strip dashes from a string?

Tags: regex, xpath

For web scraping, I need to match the last part of a URL and replace "-" dashes with " " spaces.

Code looks like this...

```
<div class="tags">
    <span class="tag" style="background-color: #5A214A;">
        <a href="/Services/Research/Telecoms-software/Service-Assurance/">SA</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to be left with "Service Assurance" (this part may contain multiple "-" dashes and require multiple replacements).

Currently being used:

Xpath:

```
//span[@class="tag"]/a/@href
```

Regex:

```
/.*/(.*)/
```

This produces "Service-Assurance", but does not strip out the "-".

I am told elsewhere that this replacement is not possible since I am already using Regex to find the string between the final "/" slashes.

Can I do both? Can I replace the "-" dashes at the end, too?

Regex is plain, inside an app called import.io, no particular language flavour.

Thank-you very much.

Comment: "no particular language flavour" - I see this statement as problematic: On the one hand, there is not necessarily such a thing as "plain regex without a specific flavour". On the other hand, it prevents us from assessing whether doing this via RegEx rather than via some other means available in your context is a good idea in the first place.

Comment: The obvious answer would be "use two regexes" (or indeed use an alternative to regexes). Presumably something make this impossible for you, or you wouldn't have asked this question, but you don't specify what makes this impossible in your question.

Comment: @Robert Can you just replace "-" by " "? With just a simple replace, without using any regex?

Comment: @hvd I believe I cannot use two regexes in the application I mentioned, import.io.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper  - If you like, "import.io" is the flavour of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath without the regex:

```
//*[@class='tag-wrapper']/input[1]/@value
```

althernatively you can also try these methods:

I scrape urls in google-sheets all the time with xpaths and regexes - so if you want to try:

```
=importXML("url goes here","//span[@class="tag"]/a/@href")
```

now then if you do at least get the url string back, then you know its working ad we can then modify it to this to get what you want:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(importXML("url goes here","//span[@class="tag"]/a/@href"),".*\/(.*)\/$"),"-"," ")
```

Let me know if you have issues - there are a couple of weird quirks with google - but if you share the url your pulling that xpath in with I can at least test it myself - i use this method now more than any others, I used to use import.io and outwit hub etc a ton

Comment: I'd rather perform the operation at the extraction stage, if possible, though this Sheets substitution function may be useful to know as I ultimately will be storing the content in Sheets.

Comment: @RobertAndrews Import.io also allows you to use it as an api which you can directly import your results into sheets, and I believe there is also a direct integration with you sheets as well.

Comment: @RobertAndrews try this xpath instead without the regex:   //*[@class='tag-wrapper']/input[1]/@value   - I just tested it, this should grab you what you want. - don't forget to change the extraction value to text instead of link also.

Comment: That xpath doesn't work (page http://www.analysysmason.com/People/Roman-Orvisky/). There actually isn't any such class "tag-wrapper". On the question of APIs to Sheets - I certainly want my extracted content to be reflected on an up-to-date sheet via API - however, I believe this is impossible since I the extractor in question is actually set to run using URLs obtained from another extractor. I've spoke with import.io directly on that. Both points are a little off course. Thanks

Comment: @RobertAndrews the tag wrapper xpath i got from a different page with the same tags that had hover overs with text, i.e this page: http://www.analysysmason.com/Research/Content/Company-profiles/Astellia-service-assurance-Dec2015-RMA01-RMA15/ - thanks for sending me the actual link - you could just run your extractors as is, and feed the strings that have your dashes in them,  to google sheets -  and just replace them in sheets after. wherein you just substitute the - for a space